# Check if cell is the last cell of Excel Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping over `MyRange` range. I need to find out if `Cell` is the last cell of `MyRange`.

```vb
For Each Cell In MyRange.Cells        
    If Cell = ' What should I write here?
        'Do some stuff
    End If
Next Cell
```

I've tried this:

```vb
If Cell = MyRange.Cells(0, MyRange.Count) Then
```

But it gives error.

How shoud I go about it?

Comment: may I ask why do you need to know that? Right after the loop finishes the `cell` variable will hold reference to the last cell that was used in the loop. Why don't you just handle what you need to handle after the loop finishes running? What if there were 2 mln cells to check? You would be checking 2 mln times if the cell is the last on - literally 2 mln times until you reach the last cell... that's a sign of bad design and bad performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like some of the other answers but shortest way could be as follow:

```
If Cell.Address = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count).Address Then
```

**Important note** This above solution will work if `myRange` is continuous range of cells.

If your area is not continuous use a logic of @Doug Glancy which in line could be presented as follow:

```
If Cell.Address = myRange.Areas(myRange.Areas.Count).Cells(myRange.Areas(myRange.Areas.Count).Cells.Count).Address Then
```

**Please!** if somebody want to reward this answer please do it automatically with @Doug Glancy answer, too (who was first).

Comment: +1 - Simple solutions are the best particularly if you don't need to loop through the object collection.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer works fine, but it's an interesting question. Here's a way to figure it out beforehand:

```
Sub test()
Dim MyRange As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim LastCell As Excel.Range

Set MyRange = Selection
Set LastCell = MyRange.Areas(MyRange.Areas.Count).Cells(MyRange.Areas(MyRange.Areas.Count).Cells.Count)
For Each cell In MyRange
If cell.Address = LastCell.Address Then
    MsgBox cell.Address
    Exit For
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Note that in both our methods, if there's more than one area, the "last cell" may not be the bottom-most or rightmost cell. For example select cells J10:J20 and then E5:E10 and run the above. The result will be E10, since it was selected last.

Comment: +1 from me to you for the solution. I used part of your code in my answer but I've set reference to your answer there :)

Answer (score 2):

I did this to reach conclusion

```
Dim i As Integer: i = 1

For Each Cell In MyRange.Cells            

    If i = MyRange.Cells.Count Then
        'Do if stuff using Cell
    Else
        'Do else stuff using Cell
    End If       

    i = i + 1

Next Cell
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can access Cells by index.
try replacing `For Each loop` with `for loop`.

I think something like this should work(untested):

```
Dim rng As Integer = myrange.Cells.Count
For i As Integer = 0 To rng - 1
            '...do something
    If i = rng Then
    End If
Next
```

Comment: +1 - This is the faster option if you need to do stuff in the loop and still gives the required information (i.e. which is the last cell).

Answer (score 1):

To check if 2 ranges are the same you can use the **intersect method** (if they don't intersect they are not the same).

```vb
Sub lastCellInForEach()
    Dim cell As Range, myrange As Range

    Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C1000")

    For Each cell In myrange.Cells
        'using Intersect to check if cell is the last cell in the range
        If Not Intersect(cell, myrange(myrange.cells.count)) Is Nothing Then
            debug.print cell.address
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```